# How does 'Iterator row selection' function work?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, iterator

How does the 'Iterator row selection' function work?

Comment: Have you checked out ESRI's documentation on that function? https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/modelbuilder-toolbox/iterate-row-selection.htm

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bulk of this answer is pulled from http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/modelbuilder-toolbox/iterate-row-selection.htm

This only works in ModelBuilder (not in an arcpy script). It allows you to iterate through a selection of rows based on field values. If you don't select something to group by, then it goes through each row of your input table and uses it as input into whatever's next in the Model. If you choose one field to group by, then all rows that correspond to each value are selected, until all of the values are exhausted.

```
objid  testfield1   testfield2
1       A            55
2       A            50
3       B            45
4       C            40
5       D            35
6       D            35
7       D            30
```

Using the example table above,

- if you included no grouping then row with objid 1 would be selected and processed, and then 2, and so on.
- if you grouped by testfield1 only, rows 1 and 2 would be selected and processed (both have fieldvalue "A"), then row 3, then row 4, then rows 5-7.
- if you grouped by testfiedl1 and testfield2 (combined), then it would process these as groups: row 1, row 2, row 3, row 4, rows 5 and 6 (both have A35), and then row 7.

> Iterate Row Selection calls Make Table View to select a table record
>   and creates two outputs: Selected Rows and Value. The output Selected
>   Rows is a Table View and can be used as inputs to other geoprocessing
>   tools that accept a Table View as input in ModelBuilder.